# .NET SQLite and Click-Once Deployment

Tags: .net, sqlite, clickonce

Have a smartclient application that is distributed using Click-Once, but also includes a SQLite DB for a local cache.

The problems is that once the app is published it doesn't seem to be able to open the SQLite DB file. Have included the DB file as part of the install process...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: Unable to open the database file

Comment: Is your deployment requesting "full trust"?

Comment: How do i setup the "full trust" thingy?

Comment: How are you creating your deployments?  Visual Studio?  If so, what version 2005, 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a ClickOnce application is set to "Full Trust", on install it will prompt the user to grant full trust.  This means that the application will have all the same privileges on the computer as the user running the application (editing the regisitry, file io, etc). You mentioned in the comments that the app is set to full trust, so it would appear that it's not a security issue.

Are you certain *all* of the necessary files are getting deployed?  I would just remove ClickOnce from the picture.  Look at all the files in your deployment, create a folder and copy all those files into it, then try to run it.  Does it work?  My initial guess is that some needed file is not being included in the ClickOnce deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Check the path that your app is using to get to the database. Virtuallized paths can cause these sorts of problems on Vista and above.

Then check the read/write permissions on the database file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the SQLite provider in the package?

Comment: Yes, its just not able to open the db file. Works fine when debugging, which makes me thing it might be a security thing?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. My solution was to add SQL.interop.DLL (x32 and x64) in the Visual Studio Project (as link) so that the ClickOne Deploiment add those files in this "package" 
Look this blog post :
http://webbercross.azurewebsites.net/ef7-sqlite-click-once-deployment-error/